# Changing the default PHP Command Path

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu Natty.

I recently installed PHP 5.3.8 from Source and it works ok. However, as part of my installation, I had to install `php5-dev` so I guess this has installed another PHP on the server (I needed to do this for phpize).

My main PHP binary is at `/usr/local/php/bin`. However, when I run php from the command line with something like this `php --ini` I get the following:

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini
```

I can still run PHP from `/usr/local/php/bin`, but that would mean me having to type the whole path out for all my command line scripts.

Is there a way I can change this behaviour so that when I use the php command, it points to the php binary inside `/usr/local/php/bin` instead?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can edit your `.bash_profile` file to change your default search path. Or update it using `PATH=/usr/local/php/bin:$PATH` or somesuch.

Comment: Not familiar with this. Where can I find that file?

Comment: It's a usually hidden file, should be in your home ~ folder. Might also be ~/.bashrc

Comment: There's a file in my /etc directory called bash.bashrc, I'm thinking this is the one?! But I have no idea what to do here, can you link me to a tutorial or something?

Comment: An easier way: `#] echo $PATH` to see what's the first entry. That's where your computer will search first. In that folder, type: `#] sudo ln -s /usr/local/php/bin/php ./php` That will create a "simlink" to the version of PHP you really want to use, so using `#] php` in your folders will execute the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for the specific circumstance in my earlier question:

```
printf "\nexport PATH=/usr/local/php/bin:\${PATH}\n" >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile
```

Hope it helps.